# groovy - How to add object to a map without null values

Tags: json, grails

Given the example code

```
Map<String,ResponseStatus> map
ResponseStatus status = new ResponseStatus(status: 200, exception: null)
map.put("test",status)
```

I got a JSON equivalent of:

```
{
"test":
  {
  "status":"200",
  "exception":null
  }
}
```

My question is, how (if it's possible) can I remove the null value from a map (or even better, how to make map ignore null values), without getting a lot of code lines.

Comment: What json serialization framework are you using?

Comment: @aristotll gson, although not really, I'm using "render map as JSON" from groovy

Comment: @pawlosek, are you looking for solution in groovy ? or java?

Comment: More likely in groovy(grails), since groovy is the only language used in my project, but would love to see the solution in java too

Comment: Do you want to remove a key as well of a null value?

Comment: Yup, the final would be
 "test":
{
"status":"200"
}